# How do I find out the distro of a Linux server?

Tags: linux

What command should I run in order to find out what distro a Linux server is running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining type of Linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/55834/determining-type-of-linux-machine)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On most modern distributions, you can query the [Linux Standard Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) system with

```
lsb_release -d
```

Sample output:

```
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.2 (lenny)
Description:    Ubuntu 9.04
```

Comment: LSB toolset seems to always be available in modern distributions, but rarely installed by default...

Comment: @freiheit - I think that says all you need to know about LSB really :-)

Comment: the command isn't present on all distros

Comment: @crk The command is likely available on all major distros but, as commented on earlier, may not be installed by default for a given distribution under common package selections.

Answer (score 3):

[I answered a similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running/11020#11020).

> For most of the popular distributions
>   then,
>
> ```
> cat /etc/*{release,version}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

For distribution name...

```
cat /etc/issue
```

For platform...

```
uname -a
```

Comment: /etc/issue is commonly replaced with a banner about authorized access as best practice in a lot of security guides, and common practice in many organizations.

Comment: yea i overwrite my /etc/issue with ascii art.

Comment: haha, excellent :)

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable for figuring out which linux distribution:

```
ls -ld /etc/*release* /etc/*version*
```

Then cat whatever files look interesting from that.

But you probably (as mentioned in another comment already) always want to run `uname -a` first, in case it isn't even a linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a routine in **VBoxSysInfo.sh**, that is part of **VirtualBox** that can be a good starting point.

However, I'd rather ask the sysadmin about this. Apart from the distribution, particular servers can have specific settings and it is frustrating to discover those right after breaking them (not to mention pissing off the sysadmin, that'll became hostile to you for being a smartass and breaking his server). I tend to treat all sysadmins as friends/teammates, there is plenty of other people to fight with: users, management etc :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `nmap -A` to let it guess the OS and version installed on a remote host

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /etc/system-release
```

for more detailed output

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: /etc/system-release is not found on Linux Mint

Comment: For OEL 8, these files are provided by the `oraclelinux-release` package, which is not a required package. Other REL-type systems likely have similarly-named packages that are also not required.